# How to access parent widget inside child widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color? color;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry? padding;
  final Widget child;
  // ... many more properties

  const MyWidget({
    super.key,
    this.color = Colors.blue,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(4),
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
      padding: padding,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

I also have another widget which wraps the above widget in `SliverToBoxAdapter` like this:

```dart
class MySliverWidget extends MyWidget {
  MySliverWidget({
    super.color,
    super.padding,
    required super.child,
    // ... many more properties
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Unable to use "child: super".
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(child: super);
  }
}
```

But the problem is I am unable to use the parent widget (`MyWidget`) instance using `super` inside the child widget (`MySliverWidget`).

So, the question is **how do I access `MyWidget` instance inside `MySliverWidget`?**

---

**Note:**

1. In `MySliverWidget.build()` method, I don't want to use `child: MyWidget(...)` and pass all the parameters to it (which is redundant).
2. I also don't to simply use `SliverToBoxAdapter(child: MyWidget(...))` instead of having a `MySliverWidget` in the first place.

Comment: tried `child: child` ?

Comment: @pskink Yes, it will work but the problem is I will not be able to use the properties passed to `MySliverWidget` then. For example, if I pass `color` to `MySliverWidget`, then how do I make use it?

Comment: `MySliverWidget(color: Colors.red)`

Comment: @pskink Yes, but where to apply that `color` property inside `MySliverWidget`? My main idea was to pass all the properties to the `MyWidget` class and then just use its instance inside `MySliverWidget` but I am not able to do that

Comment: you already applied color here: `return Container(
color: color,
padding: padding,
child: child,
);`

Comment: @pskink But that was in the `MyWidget`. Please do one thing, use `child: child` as you mentioned in the first comment and use `MySliverWidget(color: Colors.black, child: FlutterLogo())`, you'll see no `black` color applied to the logo. PS: I am leaving right now but I'll be back after an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this :

```
  return SliverToBoxAdapter(child: super.build(context));
```

Comment: I'm not very sure if this is the *right way*.